# How do I fix problems with screen when connecting a netbook to tv via VGA and audio cable?

Tags: netbook, vga, tv, connection-sharing

I have connected my Eee pc netbook to tv with VGA and audio cable. The first few times it worked wonderfully. Now it connects and you see and hear the screen however the screen on the TV is off to the left and you miss about 8cm of the computer screen. On the right side of the TV is about 8cm black. 
Now these cords and tv work perfectly with my house mates computer so I presume it's a setting on my netbook that has changed. Please help!!

Comment: "8cm" doesn't mean much when you don't provide the full size (or width) of the screen.  Are you talking about a horizontal shift of 20% of the image or just 2%?

Answer (score 0):

I've used an Eee PC with an LCD TV before and had a similar problem.

I'm not sure to the exact cause of the problem, but I simply re-detected the display and reset the resolution and the problem was quickly fixed. Under windows VISTA and 7, this can be done by right clicking on an empty area on the Desktop and selecting Screen Resolution and selecting a compatible resolution and clicking Apply. For Windows XP, this can be accomplished by going to the Control Panel and selecting "Display" and navigating to the "Settings" tab. From there you should see a slider which selects the resolution.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your idea however I've tried all the resolutions and nothing seems to work. Any more ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes this can be down to the TV itself.
Using your TV's menu, look for settings like `image position` or `image lock`
...You should be able to move the image horizontally (or vertically) such that it fits perfectly on screen.